# Cannot get image to save in desired directory using imagepng()

Tags: php, wamp

I am converting text to image using PHP's `imagettftext` function and then saving it to the server. The problem I'm having is getting it to save in the directory that I want, it has no problems saving to the current directory where the script runs.

Here is my code:

```
function txt2img($text, $fSize)
{
// Path to our font file
$fType = 'verdana.ttf';

// First we create our bounding box for the text
$bbox = imagettfbbox($fSize, 0, $fType, $text);

// We calculate the width and height using the x and y points.
// Width is: upper right corner, X position - upper left corner, X position
$width = $bbox[4] - $bbox[6] + 8;

// Height is: lower left corner, Y position - upper left corner, Y position
$height = $bbox[1] - $bbox[7] + 4;

// Determine the x position for the text to start
$x = 2;

// Determine the y position for the text to start
$y = $height - 4;

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

// Create the background color to match the website
$default = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 238, 198);

// Set the background color
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $width, $height, $default);

// Write it
imagettftext($im, $fSize, 0, $x, $y, $black, $fType, $text);

// Set the location to save the image.
//$save = "email_address.png";
$save = "../images/contact/email_address.png";

// Set the folder permissions to allow us to write to the folder.
chmod("../images/contact/",0755);

// .png tends to look better than a .jpg
imagepng($im,$save);
imagedestroy($im);
// Return the image dimensions so they can be stored in the database. This is used to properly diplay the image on the front end.
return ($width."+".$height);
}
```

If I use the $save location that is commented out, it works perfectly fine, it just isn't in the directory that I want it to be in. I have tried other paths, such as "/images/contact/email_address.png" but no joy. This also worked without the "chmod" permission change, I just added it as another option for troubleshooting. I have also gone directly to the folder and set the permissions for the user, again, no joy.

I'm running this on a local WAMP server. Also, $text has been checked and $fSize is the font size, which has also been checked. Because this works so well in the current directory, I feel this is not a coding issue as much as it is a directory issue, but that's just my view.

Answer (score 0):

So it does save in the folder you're working in as per the commented out save. Have you tried images/contact/email_address.png"; and /images/contact/email_address.png"; without the dots ? The dots are going up a level and if that's above the root it will be unaccesable to php

Comment: That's correct, it saves ok in the folder I'm working in. I have tried without the dots, but no joy.

Comment: Have a look at your php logs, What does it say there after you execute the code ? They are normally in C:\wamp\logs. The other thing you could try is using mkdir, chown and chmod to make the directory set access and then write to it, Just in case some configuration is stopping the writing.

Comment: I just had a quick look at my apache_error.log and I do see some errors associated with `imagepng()`. I'll sift through them and come back with what I find.